# Chrome browser color dotted line bug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an application with Javascript and Jquery. And also recently I have added canvas element. Now I am seeing these weird dots in chrome browser. This doesn't happen in other browsers. Is this something related to chrome ? I never experienced this before ? What is this behaviour called(any technical name for it) ?

[image]

Comment: It seems more a video card or screen problem, try moving the window (chrome) to see if dots are from screen or from  the web.

Comment: I had a problem on a previous laptop, whereby the browser window's chrome would get messed-up if the window was near the top of the screen. It was quite some time later than I finally believed the problem was due to software. Don't know if it was a Chrome update or an Nvidia one or perhaps an Asus one.

Comment: these dots appears even when the modal window is not open. It appears randomly on the screen

Comment: @enhzflep If it is a problem caused by video card,, then it should appear on all browsers right ?

Comment: @cantona_7 - indeed. Someone that wasn't an idiot would both remember the results of and have actually conducted elimination tests. Unfortunately, I am not he!

Comment: @enhzflep haha, come on !!

Comment: @Roy I have tried moving it..,its not from screen. Its from chrome !!!

Comment: @cantona_7 - okay, perhaps idiot was a touch too much - but humour aside, you made a good point. Still though, I did not conduct tests with other browsers - I knew the problem was mine, so was more concerned with dealing with it than being able to correctly identify the source. You could fairly say I took the pragmatic approach. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep jaa I get it :)

Comment: can you inspect it?

Comment: @Roy there are no special errors or messages in console. so to say any kind of warning messages. looks clean as a whistle

Comment: @cantona_7 But these lines should be in html. And again, can you inspect it? (right click at the lines and "inspect it" to see how is the html's structure.